# How to reference a dynamic range for cell validation in excel programmatically

Tags: vba, validation, excel

I'm trying to use validation to have a list of option appear as the dropdown of a cell, but I want to dynamically populate the list of options from cells otherwise generated on another sheet.  I keep getting a `1004 error: "Application-defined or object-defined error"` on the `.Add` statement.  I get this error if I use refStrg1 or refStrg2.  The referenced function I have built is performing properly.  Excel 2010.

Below is my test code:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click()
    Dim refStrg1 As String, _
        refStrg2 As String

    refStrg1 = "=indirect(" & """" & "'Sheet" & Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks").Index _
    & "'!B2:B" & getLastRowFromOf(Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks"), "B") & """" & ")"
    refStrg2 = "=Sheet" & Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks").Index _
    & "!B2:B" & getLastRowFromOf(Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks"), "B")

    With Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks").Range("F2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:=refStrg2 '<-- Error 1004
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

In debug mode I have the following watches reporting:

```
Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks").Index = 4
getLastRowFromOf(Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks"), "B") = 102
refStrg1 = "=indirect("'Sheet4'!B2:B102")"
refStrg2 = "=Sheet4!B2:B102"
```

Any help with getting the formula to reference sheet locations would be appreciated.  Also I should note that I can remove the "=" character at the begining of the reference string to get the validation on the cell to display as a single option the literal formula string (without the equals sign of course), but I really need the values as a list in those cells I'm trying to reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _You keep getting a 1004 error: "Application-defined or object-defined error"_ where?

Comment: I hit the error on the ".Add" line.

Comment: Can you `Debug.Print refStrg` just before you get the error and tell us what you see?

Comment: refStrg1 = "=indirect("'Sheet4'!B2:B102")"
refStrg2 = "=Sheet4!B2:B102"

Comment: You cannot use the "=" in the Formula1 reference string. Remove it and it should work fine.

Comment: @Matteo, without the =, I get the formula for the dropdown value instead of cell values.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce, which is to say I don't get that error and the dropdown looks good; however, I think that absolute cell references will work better, unless you want a different validation for each element of the range, F2.  e.g. `refStrg2 = "=Sheet4!$B$2:$B$102"`  (am using Excel 2010)

Comment: When I remove the "=" sign and have refStrg2 in the .Add statement this is what I see in the following.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gkwzd07hfjen6oy/ValidationIssue.png?dl=0

Comment: @Erik what version of Excel 2010 are you using, are you using any special references, what is different because I'm still getting that error.  I'm on 14.0.7149.5000 (32-bit).  Thanks for trying.

Comment: I got it to work.  Will post corrections.

Comment: I may be mistaken but I think you can do this without VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the reference string that I was producing was confusing Excel since I had renamed Sheet 4.  Using single quote marks to surround the Sheet's name rather than Sheet and its index number makes the formula1 text work.

```
refStrg2 = "='Chosen Benchmarks'!B2:B" & getLastRowFromOf(Sheets("Chosen Benchmarks"), "B")
```

Comment: In general, to avoid errors when someone (you or a user) changes a worksheet name, hard-code the codename of your worksheets, rather than the name of the worksheets. The codename is what shows up in the VBA editor's object browser, the default being Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. (notice no space). So if the VBA object is (code)named Sheet4 (and the original name was Sheet 4), use Sheet4.Name.